# VLC libx264 build error - "undefined reference to 'x264_encoder_open_128'"

Tags: linux, makefile, libav, libx264

### Primary issue

Steps to attempt to repeat this error.

- Download latest git (git://git.videolan.org/x264.git).
- Run `./configure` - You can use any options, the error is present with all.
- Run `sudo make` - It will compile all of the code but when it comes time to link the code it runs into the error

> /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(libx264.o): In function 'X264_init':
>   /.../libx264.c:418: undefined reference to 'x264_encoder_open_128'
>   
>   This will then fall out and exit make. I have removed all apt packages relating to x264. I have searched my computer for any possible libraries that might be related and removed them. This problem persists. Can someone explain what is going wrong and the simplest way to solve this?

### Additional info

This error also shows up when building [avconv](http://libav.org/index.html). It also fails at linking time with the same error. So I can assume it is nothing wrong with that directory or source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is error of linking with libavcodec.a which depends on old version of libx264. If you need only libx264 than you can compile it without lavf support (./configure --disable-lavf). If you need x264 with lavf support than you need to recompile libavcodec.a without libx264. i.e. you need to break circular dependencies between libavcodec and libx264.